# MYSQL: count column if something if another column is equal to something else

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
----------------------------------------------
|ID|Vote_Item_ID|User_ID|Country_code|   Vote|
|01|   105102151|user1  |          CA|   like|
|02|   105102151|user2  |          CA|dislike|
|03|   105102151|user3  |          UK|dislike|
|04|   105102151|user4  |          UK|   like|
|05|   105102151|user5  |          UK|   like|
----------------------------------------------
```

What I need to do is create an SQL statement that creates an array which totals the likes and dislikes for each country...The script I am using this with has 175 countries, so would this be an inefficient way to about it?

I'm not sure how to go about writing the Select statement, since I want the script to be reusable for many different "vote_item_id"s

I am using PDO with a MYSQL database by the way.

Thanks

Comment: I know the answer to the other question - you don't need to create JS using PHP at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT  Country_Code,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `like`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN vote = 'dislike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) dislike
FROM tableName
GROUP BY Country_Code
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d483bb/1)

or if you want `PreparedStatement` (*both give the same results*)

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN vote = ''',
      Vote,
      ''' then 1 Else 0 end) AS `',
      Vote, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM TableName;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT  Country_Code, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM tableName
                   GROUP BY Country_Code');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d483bb/4)

Comment: you made like as 'like' but not dislike... When its necessary?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan because `LIKE` is a [**Reserved Word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: got it! I am new to MySQL ... Even I have some unanswered questions, and waiting for answers.

Comment: @Grijesh, you have to wait a few minutes before accepting answers on stackoverflow, I will when the time expires

Answer (score 1):

If you had shown your expected output, that would have been great.
Following sample is simple. So let us know what you really need beyond this. Would be happy to pitch in. :)

REFERENCE : [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03da7/8)

CODE:

```
   SELECT t.country_code,
         sum(CASE WHEN t.vote = 'like' 
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LIKES,
         sum(CASE WHEN t.vote = 'dislike' 
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DISLIKE         
   FROM tbl t
   GROUP BY t.country_code
  ;
```

RESULTS:

```
COUNTRY_CODE    LIKES   DISLIKE
CA                1     1
UK                2     1
```